# Get output for each id in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I wrote a logic for getting the difference in days for present status a next status for a particular sub status and application.

```
select * from (
   select datediff(day,presentstatusdate,nextstatusdate) 
   from timeline 
   where type="status' 
   and application='a123' ) as a 
where sub_status='docs'
```

Here it is giving the expected result.

I am struggling to understand the logic, where if I need daysdiff for all applications. i.e If i remove the application field from the query, it is not giving expected result.

```
select * from (
   select datediff(day,presentstatusdate,nextstatusdate) 
   from timeline 
   where type="status' 
   and application=(
      select distinct application 
      from timline 
      where timeline.application=a.application ) 
    ) as a 
where sub_status='docs'
```

Comment: `application = (select...)` should be `application in (select...)`

Comment: You can't refer to `a.application` inside the query with alias `a`.

Comment: If you want all applications, just get rid of `and application = ...`

Comment: The first query can't work as you've written it. The subquery doesn't return `sub_status`, so you can't use `where sub_status = 'docs'`